# Stub returns stub - bad practice?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, return, stub

Suppose I have a class **DataProvider** which implements **IDataProvider** interface. **IDataProvider** defines a method **IData GetData()**.
In addition there is a class **Consumer** which should call this function any 5 seconds to be up to date.
Here is a short code example which describes the above definitions:

```
interface IDataProvider{
  IData GetData();
}

class Consumer{
  IDataPRovider m_provider;
  Consumer(IDataProvider provider){
    m_provider = provider;
  }
}
```

Now, to test the Consumer class in complete isolation I should create **two stubs**. More accurate, **DataProviderStub** which returns **DataStub**.
As I understood from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678166/how-to-avoid-returning-mocks-from-a-mocked-object-list) topic, stub which returns stub is a possible problem with a design.

**1. Why exactly it is a problem? What issues it may cause?

  2. How can I redesign it in order to avoid stub which returns stub, but still stick to DI principles and have some level of abstraction?**

Answer (score 0):

A stub isn't a the same as a mock. You don't have to specifically account for every bit of behaviour of a stub. Therefore **it isn't really a problem** - you are not having to write `dataProviderMock.GetData.andReturn(mockData)` and likewise for the mock of `IData` for every time `GetData` is called, nor do you have to get this in the right order.

(If Data is just a POJO / Bean, I would recommend returning the actual object rather than a stub.)

Comment: And what if it's not a POJO? If I'll return the actual object, I'll brake the abstraction and my unit test will depend on actual implementation of IData. Which is not good as well...

Comment: @binyan sure, if it's not a POJO, you should probably stub it

Comment: Which returns us to questions above :)